# Upgrade to Android jet brains Studio broke my app - import statements not recognised

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I went back to an old app of mine which I wanted to upgrade and when I ran the jet brains studio, it advised me that updates were available. So, I clicked on the commit button and left it to its own devices.

Except it has broken my android app (which relies on Google maps).

The following packages are said to be unused:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.VisibleRegion;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
```

However, looking at the developers pages (such as https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary), the packages are being declared correctly. Oddly, the app compiles OK, or at least I get nothing say compilation failed, but consequently the app doesn't show the Map background, although markers are put on OK, and I can click on them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you do a clean rebuild or invalidate cache?

Comment: I did yes, both of them.

Comment: what happens when you delete those "un-used" imports? This seems odd.

Comment: I still get the tooltop saying unused import, and the red wibbly underline thing indicating the portion it doesn't recognise) - for instance, "import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory", the "android" is underlined.

Comment: Try deleting the .idea folder in your project. Close and restart ide. Open/import your project if prompted. Then, clean and rebuild your project. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work - I did as you said but had to reboot my laptop. I don't know why it didn't seem to work. The lack of google map (even though markers are showing) is another issue it would seem. I'm still scratching my head over that one!

Comment: @user3713442 is your issue solved? I will turn this comment into an answer. Kindly, accept it. Also, feel free to post another question if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes on upgrading Android Studio or any IDE, some old files of previous IDE are left behind.

Try deleting the .idea folder in your project. Close and restart ide. Open/import your project if prompted. Then, clean and rebuild your project.